# How to load a image from network share into BitmapImage control?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I have an application that runs on Raspberry Pi using Windows IoT and C#. In said application I have a URI to an image on a public network share that I want to load into an Image by setting the source attribute. Is this possible?

I've tried:

```
App.FrontImage = "\\172.xx.x.xx/O Drive/0_Customers/CUSTOMERNAME/CUSTOMERENTITY/Art/photo.jpg";
```

then

```
frontImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(App.FrontImage));
```

Where frontImage is my Image....
I'm returned a URI that is usable in Windows Explorer, so the path is correct, however am I blocked by some stream issues?

Comment: See [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).

Comment: According to the documentation it states this is Windows Store apps only for UNC access. My app is internal to my company and therefore not going to be in the app store.

Comment: Honestly, after reviewing about a 100 questions and looking around it's seeming the only solution is to create an API call that can pull the data from the location.

Is it seriously this difficult?

Comment: Yes I did. Which led me to implementing a version of (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190333/windows-8-storagefile-getfilefrompathasync-using-unc-path). Which was unsuccessful.

This continued to follow down the rabbit hole of attempts at different approaches until I read numerous reports of people abandoning this process to use an API to return the images from server.

Has this ever been fully implemented?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/e822c960-f15d-4789-9ff2-040212d0a67c/uwpaccess-a-file-on-a-network-drive?forum=wpdevelop)?

Comment: No, I since moved to another approach by using a REST API to retrieve and return the images via base64 encoded string which I then place into the image control.